# How to make a URL API more secure

Tags: php, ios, url

I've implemented a PHP URL API which I'm calling from my iPhone App in order to access certain data on my server. I'm not certain how to make it so that only my app is allowed to call the API. My incredibly simple solution, until now, has been to pass a key in the URL but it can easily be cached if someone wants to and then used by unwanted users. What should I do?

Comment: Well, if you want to send some secrets on a HTTP request, at least you should secure it using SSL and use HTTPS instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track to use a secret key, but use that key to create a hash that you pass with the URL instead of the key. The server has the same key and can recreate the same hash. If it doesn't match, then it's not valid.

```
$key = 'my secret key';
$data_item1 = 'something';
$data_item2 = 'something else';

$random_key = mt_rand(100000,10000000);
$check = sha1($key . $data_item1 . $data_item2 . $random_key);

$submit_data = array(
    'data_item1' => $data_item1,
    'data_item2' => $data_item2,
    'check' => $check,
    'checkid' => $random_key
);
```

The server has the same $key as the app. It can then take the data elements submit and run the same sha1 and compare the sha1 results. You don't need to use all the data items you are submitting to create the sha1 hash. The important part is leaving out some "key" data from the submission to generate the hash. This also verifies that the data wasn't changed or tampered with in transit since it acts a sort of checksum.

The random data is to make sure every request has a different hash so it's harder to detect patterns. This method should be sufficient to deter casual hacking.

Answer (score 0):

How about requiring a username and a password?
A simple (but not perfect) approach could be [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Do your communication over HTTPS. I would have the application do a preliminary check with the server. If the server responds in a certain way (for example, with a specific status code or response string), then the app knows it is legitimate. Then the app can post information to the PHP API and perhaps use a username and password to authenticate (or if you really want to be complex, have the server return a passcode on the preliminary check and use that to authenticate to the service).

By communicating over HTTPS, you are ensuring everything is encrypted. By doing a preliminary check, you can be more confident that someone doesn't create a fake SSL certificate to put on their fake server to grab your authentication details. The app then finishes the response securely. This system is more complex, so this should be safer.

By the way, be careful about putting sensitive usernames and passwords in your code. If someone decompiles your executable, they could be able to see them. Choose to do something more dynamic, like grabbing the passcode after a preliminary check with the server.